Animating Instance on points with objects - Objects jump
i ran in to some problems with animating objects distributed with geometry nodes (points on instances) and the waving animation of this objects with a displacement modifier driven by a cloud texture, wich is controlled via empty following a circle path to loop the animation. My problem is, that the objects jump in position and rotation like the changing geometry comming with the displacement let the geometry nodes recalculate the distribution and maybe rotation. Here is an example clip of my problem and some screenshots of the geometry nodes and modifierstack:
https://youtu.be/-NTIox0KgjM
Geometry Nodes:

Modifier Stack:


I solved the problem with much more subdivisions. Render intensiv but acurate.
